# Logout doesn't work with Spring Boot and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf, logout

This is my code using Spring Boot and Spring Security. The problem is when I used to logout (using *Thyemleaf*) the logout doesn't work for me.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials,active from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username as principal,roles as role from users_roles where username=?")
                .rolePrefix("ROLE_")
                .passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index1").permitAll();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .logout();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/adpage").hasRole("ADMIN");
        http
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        http
            .logout().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Link using Thyemleaf:

```html
<li><a th:href="@{/login?logout}">logout</a></li>
```

Comment: everything works except the logout ,i mean the session doesn't expired when i click the logout link , for example i'm a user, i signup(login) and hence i logout i still get the access to the user page

Comment: See my answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885178/logout-is-not-working-in-spring-security. You have to use HTTP `POST` and the URL is only `/logout`.

Answer (score 6):

Try doing something like this.

```
 <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="Log out"/>
 </form>
```

Spring security logout Url is POST only. You can support Non-POST logout by changing your Java Configuration

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    // ...
    .logout()
       .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
}
```

this way you can logout user using GET request

```
<li><a th:href="@{/logout}">logout</a></li>
```

Comment: yeah it works ,i already did this solution by using a form* , but for the  second when i tried it ,i get  an error in the text editor(Eclipse) ..
Many thanks @ahsan ;)

Comment: This is a documented solution and it should work. Can you show me the error. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout

Answer (score -1):

Try the following instead:

```
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?login_error=true")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") //if needed
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index1").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/adpage").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index") //or whatever page you want
                .logoutUrl("/logout") //thinking this is what you need
                .permitAll();
```

And your link would be:

```
<li><a th:href="@{/logout}">logout</a></li>
```